Why does git diff master...MYBRANCH give different results than git diff MYBRANCH...master?
I normally just do git diff master...MYBRANCH but for some reason I did it backward (git diff MYBRANCH...master) and it gave no result. This surprised me and made me want to double-check it, and I realized I had typed the command backward.  Why do these two commands give different results?

Why is 4 minus 3 different from 3 minus 4? Because of the definition of "minus". Here's a related answer with a super quick explanation of 3 dots. No output for master on the right means MYBRANCH is fully up to date with master.

It isn't clear what you can mean by "why" here; it's simply a matter of what the ... notation in git diff means. In other words, it works that way because that's how the authors of Git designed it.
The expression compares the merge-base commit of the two specified commits to the second commit. Thus it is trivially obvious that it matters which of the two commits is second.
Extra credit: If, as often happens, you are on MYBRANCH at the time you give this command, you can omit MYBRANCH from the expression; just say git diff master...

Nice extra credit. I usually type git diff master...@ but you've reminded me that I've been typing that extra character unnecessarily.
